# Find inactive users on an active directory group?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, account

I want to find the inactive users on an AD group that hasn't used either server since last year. I don't want to find the inactive users for whole AD just a specific group. Any PowerShell command that can do that?

I tried:

```
Get-AdGroupMember -identity “Groupname” –AccountInactive -DateTime ‘1/12020’ –ResultPageSize 2000 –ResultSetSize $null | 
?{$_.Enabled –eq $True} | select name | 
Export-CSV -path
```

and I also tried the following:

```
Get-AdGroupMember -identity “Groupname” | select name, lastlogon
```

In the first one, it gives me an error that does not recognize the parameters `AccountInnactive` and `Datetime` and with the second command the `lastlogon` table it is empty

Comment: Please update your question with what you are currently trying along with the specific errors/issues you are getting :-)

Comment: I was trying this but it gives me errors: Get-AdGroupMember -identity “Groupname” –AccountInactive -DateTime ‘1/12020’ –ResultPageSize 2000 –ResultSetSize $null | ?{$_.Enabled –eq $True} | select name | Export-CSV -path

Comment: The simple answer is yes. Please put what you tried right into your post. If you got errors post those also.

Answer (score 2):

```
$DaysInactive = 90  
$time = Get-Date 
Get-ADGroupMember "*GroupName*" -Recursive | get-aduser -Properties lastlogon | 
where {[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon) -lt ($time).Adddays(-($DaysInactive)) -and $_.enabled -eq $true } | 
select name,@{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
```

In the above we are piping the results of `Get-ADGroupMember` to `get-aduser` explicitly asking for the lastlogon details (with the `-properties lastlogon`) as it is not one of the default properties the cmdlet displays this attribute would have no value without it.

We further narrow down our results by piping the results from the `get-aduser` to the `where-object` cmdlet applying our date comparisons.  To compare the date we are first converting the lastlogon value to [DateTime] `[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)` the same type in use by `Get-Date` allowing us to compare